# Git workflow: PDT + Egit on Eclipse workspace and Git bare repository

Tags: eclipse, egit, git-bare

I'm developing a Symfony applicatoin and I'm trying to set up a Git workflow on Eclipse. The workspace (where the project files lies) are located on `/home/sfprojects/testing/` and the Git repository is located on `/var/git/testing`.

Reading over and over all the Git resources I've could found (including "Pro Git" by Scott Chacón, and the EGit user guide (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide, among others), it's easy to understand why the Git repository and the Eclipse workspace should not share the same directory, now my big confusion is that I can not see a method to keep both things separated from each other.

Once I've created the Git repository through the wizard, all the project files are moved automatically from the Eclipse workspace to the working directory on `/var/git/testing/testing/`. For my big surprise, the new created Git repository became into the new project workplace on Eclipse with .git directory in the parent directory. It is not a obvious contradiction?. If I let the mouse pointer over the option "Use or create repository in parent folder of project" a very clear help tag with the following text:

> When checked, this wizard will try to find or create a repository in the parent folder hierarchy of the selected projects.
>
> Typically, newly created projects are located in the Eclipse workspace, thus repositories created this way would also end up in the Eclipse workspace.
>
> This is not recommended for several reasons explained in the EGit user guide.

So, after some research, my logical conclusion is to create a Git bare repository and then link it to the project located in the workspace... wrong! bare repositories are not available to a Eclipse project.

I need a serious explanation on this.

Comment: The user guide recommends against it because there were people which just deleted their workspace folder (or the project including contents) and then were surprised that their Git repository data was also deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I've read it like a ten times. But that's just one of four (or maybe five) reasons to DON'T mix up a Git repository with the Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I went wrong about what I thought was a contradiction in the EGit User Guide and the EGit behaviour about moving the project directory to the Git repository.

When the project files are moved as a working directory of the Git repository (with a Git metadata folder at the same level), they're still  under the Eclipse control, as Eclipse workspace. But as EGit User Guide says (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_Workspace_and_Repository_working_directory), the .git metadata folder should NOT be into the workspace... well that's when I was wrong, cause it is a Eclipse project/Git working folder... but it IS NOT an Eclipse workspace by any means, so the Git metadata folder is not editable, as any other source project file, just for Git (and the EGit Eclipse plugin, of course).